# Где найти Prettify подсветку для Delphi или как переделать в неё подсветку Pascal?

Tags: javascript, delphi, pascal

Есть в интернете файл `lang-delphi.js` для посветки Delphi на Prettify? Или можно как-то изменить `lang-pascal.js`, чтобы он работал правильно? В настоящий момент работать нормально не хочет - все слова, начинающиеся с большой буквы, помечает классом `typ`.

```js
prettyPrint();
```

```css
.str { color: #060 }
.kwd { color: #006; font-weight: bold }
.com { color: #600; font-style: italic }
.typ { color: red; font-weight: bold }
.lit { color: #044 }
.pun, .opn, .clo { color: #440 }
.tag { color: #006; font-weight: bold }
.atn { color: #404 }
.atv { color: #060 }
```

```html
<pre class="prettyprint">
    Function FunctionName(Param: Type): Result;
    Begin
    
    End;
    function functionname(param: type): result;
    begin
    
    end;
    FUNCTION FunctionName BEGIN END;
</pre>
```

Как видим, ни один из вариантов не подсвечен правильно. Вся суть проблемы видна в первом варианте - все слова, начинающиеся с большой буквы, раскрашены красным (помечены классом `typ`), но такого быть не должно. Второй вариант самый приемлемый, но нужна возможность начинать имена переменных и функций с большой буквы - это в Delphi часто применяется.

Также, и ключевые слова (например, `Function`) в идеале должны быть регистронезависимы.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате, что вы делали для ее решения и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Проблема в том, что подсветка очень ограничена в ресурсах, а полноценный анализ некоторых языков очень трудоёмок. Кроме того, языки постоянно развиваются, и поддерживать грамматики в идеальном состоянии банально некому. Поэтому используется компромиссное решение: подсвечивать ключевые слова независимо от контекста, подсвечивать в соответствии с какими-то традициями наименования и т. п.

Comment: Например, C# полностью пролетает по всем параметрам: грамматика очень сложная, много контексто-зависимых ключевых слов, правила именования расходятся с "джавовыми", поэтому проблемы те же, что и у дельфи, только ещё хуже. Собственно, посмотрите на код — там кроме регулярок ничего нет. Очевидно, что регулярками полноценно подсветить код на любом языке невозможно в принципе.

Comment: Смиритесь, такова судьба всех мертвых языков. Я пытался найти форматтер кода для дельфи (просто отступы чтобы расставить, онлайн или оффлайн), не нашел. Ну кроме самой IDE, которая у меня не установлена

Comment: Discord, то есть, единственный выход - форматировать код при добавлении с учетом определенных правил (имена параметров с маленькой буквы и т.д.)?

zenden2k, латинский язык мертвый. И древнерусский. А на Delphi пишут и очень часто.

Answer (score 1):

Я вот какой то плагин на [github](https://github.com/rkennedy/prettify-pascal) нашел, возможно это то что нужно.

Google Prettify plug-in for Pascal and Delphi syntax highlighting

Comment: К сожалению, та же проблема - все слова, начинающиеся с большой буквы, подсвечиваются с классом `typ`.